# Detect jQuery undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this bit of script

```
 $('a').on('click', function () {
     var vIDString = this.getAttribute('id');
     if (vIDString === undefined) {
         //do nothing
         alert('Hit undefined')
     } else {
         var vID = vIDString.substring(8);
     }
 })
```

I have tried x === undefined, x === 'undefined', typeof x === undefined, typeof x === 'undefined' and everthing else I can think of, and it happily skips over that and throws 'Unable to get property 'substring' of undefined or null reference'

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: what is the value of, and what do you get if you log `vIDString`?

Comment: undefined is the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never get **undefined**. Indeed, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

> getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string); see Notes for details.

Hence you need to test against null or empty string:

```js
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var vIDString = this.getAttribute('id');
    if (vIDString == null ||  vIDString.length == 0) {
        //do nothing
        console.log('Hit undefined')
    } else {
        console.log('ID is: ' + vIDString);
        //var vID = vIDString.substring(8);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="url">link text with no ID</a><br/>
<a id="IDVALUE" href="url">link text</a>
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Still find the use of =, == and === rather confusing

Comment: @gchq `=` is for assignment, e.g. `var x = 5`. `==` and `===` is for comparison, the latter being stricter than the former. You should almost always use `===`.

Comment: Terry - thanks for clearing that up. After decades of VB some nuances seem counter intuitive with the 'squiggly line code' :-)